# Characterizing the relationship between element-wise Markov transitions and the full-conditionals of the stationary distribution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ergodic-theory, markov-chains

Consider a $p$ dimensional random variable with a discrete support. Consider a Markov transition kernel on the state space that is defined in terms of element-wise transition distributions.

One can find examples of transition kernels that are

a) irreducible, implying that the corresponding Markov chain has a (unique) stationary distribution

but for which

b) the element-wise transition distributions are incompatible in the sense that they do not correspond to the conditional distributions of any joint distribution (see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2289858#metadata_info_tab_contents) for conditions).

The well-known Gibbs sampling algorithm corresponds to the situation where the conditional distributions of a given joint distribution describe element-wise transition distributions that have the corresponding joint as the stationary distribution.

I had always assumed (incorrectly) that if a set of full-conditionals were incompatible that they must not have a stationary distribution.

> Now that I know that incompatible conditional distributions (considered as
>   element-wise transition distributions) *can* have a stationary
>   distribution, I'm wondering if there is any way to characterize the
>   relationship between the conditional distributions of the stationary
>   distribution and the specified transition distributions.

My intuition (often faulty) is that they ought to be somehow close to one another, perhaps the nearest set of conditionals (in some sense) to the prescribed transition distributions.

I suspect this may be known to people working in this area and a reference would be much appreciated.

---

Here is a concrete example: Let $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ be a random vector with each element taking the values 0 or 1, so $X \in \{0, 1\}^3$. Consider the transition probabilities defined by making one of the following moves uniformly at random:
$$\mbox{Pr}(X_1^{(t+1)} =1,X_2^{(t+1)} = X_2^{(t)}, X_3^{(t+1)} = X_3^{(t)} \mid X^{(t)}) = 0.35 + 0.5X_2 - 0.25X_3,$$
$$\mbox{Pr}(X_1^{(t+1)} = X_1^{(t)}, X_2^{(t+1)} =1, X_3^{(t+1)} = X_3^{(t)} \mid X^{(t)}) = 0.10 + 0.75X_1 + 0.10X_3,$$
$$\mbox{Pr}(X_1^{(t+1)} = X_1^{(t)}, X_2^{(t+1)} = X_2^{(t)}, X_3^{(t+1)} =1 \mid X^{(t)}) = 0.50 + 0.25X_1 - 0.10X_2,$$
with the obvious complement probabilities and all other transition probabilities on the 2^3 = 8 dimensional state space are zero. This transition kernel defines a Markov chain with a stationary distribution, but these transitions cannot be interpreted as conditional distributions (by erasing the superscripts) because they are incompatible. Indeed, one way to see that they are incompatible is to check that they differ from the conditional distributions of the stationary distribution. If they were compatible, the Markov chain would define a Gibbs sampler.

Here is an [R script](https://math.la.asu.edu/~prhahn/markov.demo.R) implementing this example, confirming the stationary distribution and examining one of the conditional distributions.

---

**Motivation**: Iteratively sampling from potentially incompatible conditional distributions is done routinely to impute missing data, making this question of some importance to applied data analysis. It apears that this is an open problem, at least among applied statisticians; I'm posting here in hopes that a way forward might be obvious to a theoretician who studies stochastic processes. Here are some relevant references [3](http://ftp.stat.duke.edu/WorkingPapers/11-24.pdf) [4](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/mi_theory9.pdf) [5](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2014.948117) [6](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4572746/pdf/nihms635326.pdf).

Comment: I have trouble understanding the setup, i.e. how precisely the described transition kernel and the joint distribution / stationary distribution are related in your setting. Could you make the question more precise with some formulas?

Comment: @Steve I added an example and a computational demonstration in R if that is helpful.

Comment: @Steve I have also added several motivating references, which include other concrete examples.